# ADF Transformation with parameterized dataset in mapping data flow

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk

I'm currently doing an ADF data transformation using .net SDK. I’m using Data Flow for this transformation. I have a CSV file with three columns which are First Name, Last Name and Age. I want to Concatenate First Name and Last Name in to full Name.
But the problem is input file is generated at runtime (Data sets are parameterized). Below is my Data Flow Diagram. I also tried adding parameters for Concat function.

[image]

I was able to do this for an existing file in blob storage and below is that Data Flow Diagram.

[image]

But I want to do this with a file which is created at runtime. Please assist

Comment: Why not concatenate columns in the file generation logic itself. This feature is not supported in data flow.

Comment: Will the column names, data types, and number of columns be variable between each execution?

Comment: @RaunakJhawar Thank you but I found a solution for this

Comment: @MarkKromer Yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will work inside of a Derived Column regardless of the contents of the incoming file, so long as FirstName and LastName exist somewhere in the incoming metadata:

byName('FirstName')+byName('LastName')

Comment: I have changed my data flow script in the json a bit by adding columns as inputs. Now it's wroking. Thanks